# random column name generated by azure sql

Tags: json, azure-sql-database

I'm noticing when I make any `select` statement with json data outputs a column name with random title e.g.

```
select 'john' as firstname, 'smith' lastname  for json path
```

if I run this in sql management studio (text results) I'll get

> JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B
>   -------------------------------------------- [{"firstname":"john","lastname":"smith"}]
>
> (1 row(s) affected)

How to change the column name of the generated json data. I've tried using the root option but couldn't override the column title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same as using XML.
you cannot set the column name
for my opinion since you will always get single row and single column (which means that this is only one value) 
the column name have no meaning. but maybe you have different scenario that i am not aware of.

anyway, if you want to workaround it you can use this query

```
select (select 'john' as firstname, 'smith' lastname  for json path) as MyColumn
```